# Filter issues with Adjacent Groups

Tags: reporting-services, filter, ssrs-grouping

I am building a report in SSRS.

I have a return set like something below:

```
store, name, filter, data
1      Hol   1       1.5
2      Nam   2       3.5
3      Hol   3       1.5
2      Nam   3       3.5
```

Now the issue is I have a table with 3 adjacent groups.  In each group I have put a filter to filter by the filter (group 1 filters results with a filter of 1) etc.

The issue that is presenting itself is the fact that the table seems to filter only the first filter result.

I will get a table result like the following:

```
Hol    1.5
```

I will not even get my other two rows to process.  I know the data is there because if I put a filter on the whole table for 3 and just let the filters at the group level work I get:

```
Hol 1.5
Nam 3.5
```

It's like the first filter that is processed is the only filter that it looks at.

If I do a total though without a group filter but with the table filter it brings back **8.0**.

This problem is driving me insane.  The data is there with individual filters, tested in MS and query designer within SSRS.

The adjacent groups however are not filtering results separately.

Comment: "I have put a filter to filter by the filter" o.O would you consider rephrasing bits of your question? It's a bit hard to follow at some points.

Comment: That looks like it is doing exactly what you want - `filter = 1` returns the only row where `filter` equals 1 and if you set it to 3 then it returns the two rows where `filter` equals 3. I'm not sure what else you were expecting. Maybe you could explain your problem better?